# Forum on Python and GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, forum

Are there any forums that work on GAE Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [FoFou forums](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/fofou/index.html) are specifically designed for GAE Python.

There is also a version of PyIB's Python-based forums which will run on app engine: http://code.google.com/p/pyib/